# Manual approval task in step function - invoke through a script

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a step function with an activity task that should wait for an input from a script that I will run from my terminal. If the script is invoked, the task that is waiting  should get succeeded

Could someone provide examples on how to achieve this?

Any helpful documentations or referenced code links are appreciated.
Would I need an activity worker to invoke this?
Can a script running in my terminal invoke the lambda and mark it as succeeded?

[image]

```
node report-choice-step-success.js --stepfunction-arn <SFN-EXEC> --step-name ManualTask
```

Script report-choice-step-success.js

```
const main = () => {
    let sfnClient;
    const rolename =  `StepFunctionExecuter-LOCAL`;

    return getcreds({ accountId: '123456789012', region: 'us-east-1', rolename })
        .then(params => {
            sfnClient = new AWS.StepFunctions(params)
        })
        
        .then(() => startmystepfunction(sfnClient));
};




const startmystepfunction = (sfnClient) => {
    const stateMachineArn = `arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:stateMachine:MYSTEPFUNCTION`;
    const name = `Manual step`;

    const executionParams = { name, stateMachineArn };
    return sfnClient.startExecution(executionParams).promise()
           .then(response => {
                if (response && response.executionArn) { 
                    print(`Started SFN execution for arn: ${response.executionArn}`);)
};
```

How should I modify the task so that it waits for a manual input so that it gets succeeded?

```
{
  "Comment": "My state machine",
  "StartAt": "Manual step",
  "States": {
    "ManualStep": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::activity:manualtask",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement this without an activity worker? I am confused as to :
1. how to make the manual task wait ?
2. what is the parameter that I should send in my script to invoke the manual task change that is waiting and change its  status to succeeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the Activity ARN from the executionARN using the `getExecutionHistory` method and filtered the scheduled activities.
Then I used that particular activityARN to `getActivityTask` and then used the sendTaskSuccess method to transition the step to succeeded.

```
sfnClient.getActivityTask(params).promise()
  .then(data => {
    var params = {
      output: data.input.toString(),
      taskToken: data.taskToken.toString()
    };

    sfnClient.sendTaskSuccess(params).promise()

  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    console.error(err.stack);
  });
```